# Generate Table dynamically with AJAX data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically generate a table with JavaScript using AJAX and displayed using Bootstrap but I can't seem to get the table to show.It only shows the header fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<button onclick="display();">Generate Table</button>
<div id="myTable"></div>




function display(){

  var HTML = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' style='width:500px'>";

  HTML += "<tr><th>Place</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

  var search = 106;

  makeRequest('findplace.php?searchbynumber='+search,function(data){
    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
      HTML += "<tr><td>" + data[i].place + "</td><td>" + data[i].description + "</td></tr>";
    }
  });

  HTML += "</table>";

  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = HTML;
}

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  var request;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  } else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
  }

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      callback(request);
    }
  }

  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't generate the table in php? Or do you need the data for something other than just displaying?

Comment: I'm sure he COULD generate the table in php, but sending the full HTML of a table can be a lot of data compared to a little bit of JSON. When rendering DOM elements based on AJAX responses, it's generally best to send a little data as possible, and then let the client construct the DOM based on that data.

Comment: The problem here is that your table constructing code is being executed asynchronously in a callback. By the time it gets executed, the closing tag for the table has already been written to the global variable and written to the document.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota my php suggestion is because I was thinking that is going to be easier for a beginner to get working.

Comment: @TimSeguine, yes I'm using the data to display some data using Google Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim says in the comment, this is to do with the asynchronous nature of the call you're making in `makeRequest`.

You essentially build the outside of the table and add that the HTML, then the callback is called later, builds up a new variable and never does anything with it.

You have a number of options, but the simplest is probably to move the creation of the HTML into the callback and build it in one go on return from the `onreadychangestate` and you have everything you need to output.

I.E. Move ALL the HTML construction into your callback and the problem should go away:

```
function display(){

  var search = 106;

  makeRequest('findplace.php?searchbynumber='+search,function(data){

    var HTML = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' style='width:500px'>";

    HTML += "<tr><th>Place</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
      HTML += "<tr><td>" + data[i].place + "</td><td>" + data[i].description + "</td></tr>";
    }

    HTML += "</table>";

    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = HTML;

  });
}

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  var request;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  } else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
  }

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      callback(request);
    }
  }

  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
}
```

As for other options:

As one idea, you could build the outside of the table as you do, but with a "Loading..." bit of text in there and then add the rows in the callback - but if you're looking for that I'd say that's an exercise for the reader...

Comment: +1 Easiest change to OP's code that does what they want.

Comment: Thank you! It worked instantly and also for the tip.